# How to delete Row in table on 'Delete' button

Tags: javascript

I want to have a better solution to my problem. Instead of removing the innerText values and hiding the delete button.
It's leaving space in the form since it's not removed but hidden. The object is successfully removed from the array, but how can I remove the entire row?
Any help or hint is appreciated!

```js
// Student Constructor Object
let students = [];
function Student(id, name, surname, points){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.points = points;
    this.DidPass = function(){
        if(this.points > 50){
            console.log('PASS');
        }else if(this.points < 50){
            console.log('FAILED')
        }
    }
}

// Create Student

function createStudent(){
    let studentId = document.getElementById('studentID').value;
    let studentName = document.getElementById('studentName').value;
    let studentSurname = document.getElementById('studentSurname').value;
    let studentPoints = document.getElementById('studentPoints').value;


    let newStudent = new Student(studentId,studentName,studentSurname,studentPoints);
    students.push(newStudent);


    let PassNot = true;
    for(let i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
        PassNot = students[i].DidPass();
    }

    // Delete Btn
    let btnDelete = document.createElement('button');
    btnDelete.classList.add('btnDelete');
    btnDelete.innerHTML = 'Delete Record'
    btnDelete.onclick = function(){
        for(let j = 0; j < students.length; j++){
            if(studentId == students[j].id){
                students.splice(j);
                tdShowID.innerText = '';
                tdShowName.innerText = '';
                tdShowSurname.innerText = '';
                tdShowPoints.innerText = '';
                tdShowDidPass.innerText = '';
                btnDelete.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }

    
    let table = document.getElementById('table')
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let tdShowID = document.createElement('td');
    tdShowID.innerText = studentId;
    let tdShowName = document.createElement('td');
    tdShowName.innerText = studentName;
    let tdShowSurname = document.createElement('td');
    tdShowSurname.innerText = studentSurname;
    let tdShowPoints = document.createElement('td');
    tdShowPoints.innerText = studentPoints;
    let tdShowDidPass = document.createElement('td');
    tdShowDidPass.innerText = PassNot;



    table.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(tdShowID);
    table.appendChild(tdShowName);
    table.appendChild(tdShowSurname);
    table.appendChild(tdShowPoints);
    table.appendChild(tdShowDidPass);
    table.appendChild(btnDelete);


}

// Logic
function checkIfStudentExists(studentId){
    return students.some(student => student.id === studentId);
}

// Create Student
let btnSubmit = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
btnSubmit.onclick = function(){
    createStudent();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = './style/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>Student App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="formField" class = 'flx'>
            <label for = 'studentID'>Student ID</label>
            <input id = 'studentID' name = 'studentID' placeholder = 'student ID' required>
            <label for = 'studentName'>Student Name</label>
            <input id = 'studentName' name = 'studentName' placeholder = 'student name' required>
            <label for = 'studentSurname'>Student Surname</label>
            <input id = 'studentSurname' name = 'studentSurname' placeholder = 'student surname' required>
            <label for = 'studentPoints'>Student Points</label>
            <input id = 'studentPoints' name = 'studentPoints' placeholder = 'student points' required>
            <button id = 'btnSubmit'>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="results">
            <table id = 'table'>
                <tr>
                    <td>Student ID</td>
                    <td>Student Name</td>
                    <td>Student Surname</td>
                    <td>Student Points</td>
                    <td>Student Grade</td>
                    <td>Delete Record</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id = 'tr'>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src = './js/app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to use the click event to get the containing `td` - from there, get the containing `tr` - then `.style.display = "none"` on that `tr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems to correct prior to resolving the spacing/hiding issue.

1. Your table is not being formed properly. If you look your output you'll see that the student data is simply placed between `<tr>` tags rather *inside* the `tr` tag.
2. Your header row is in a `tr` rather than a `td`. There is nothing wrong with this unless you want to do something specific with *only the table body*.
3. There is no `tbody` element - there should be since it makes your coding easier
4. You placed everything into the `table` element. The `tr` elements are the only thing that goes in to the `table` - note I change that to `tbdody`

Now with all those things fixed up, the answer to your question is to add the following code to your `click` handler for your `button`:

```js
  e.target.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(e.target.parentElement);
```

That will delete the `tr` from the table.

Which you'll see implemented below:

```js
// Student Constructor Object
let students = [];

function Student(id, name, surname, points) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.points = points;
  this.DidPass = function() {
    if (this.points > 50) {
      console.log('PASS');
    } else if (this.points < 50) {
      console.log('FAILED')
    }
  }
}

// Create Student

function createStudent() {
  let studentId = document.getElementById('studentID').value;
  let studentName = document.getElementById('studentName').value;
  let studentSurname = document.getElementById('studentSurname').value;
  let studentPoints = document.getElementById('studentPoints').value;


  let newStudent = new Student(studentId, studentName, studentSurname, studentPoints);
  students.push(newStudent);


  let PassNot = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    PassNot = students[i].DidPass();
  }

  // Delete Btn
  let btnDelete = document.createElement('button');
  btnDelete.classList.add('btnDelete');
  btnDelete.innerHTML = 'Delete Record'
  btnDelete.onclick = function(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(e.target.parentElement);
    for (let j = 0; j < students.length; j++) {
      if (studentId == students[j].id) {
        students.splice(j);
        tdShowID.innerText = '';
        tdShowName.innerText = '';
        tdShowSurname.innerText = '';
        tdShowPoints.innerText = '';
        tdShowDidPass.innerText = '';
        btnDelete.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }


  let tableBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  let tdShowID = document.createElement('td');
  tdShowID.innerText = studentId;
  let tdShowName = document.createElement('td');
  tdShowName.innerText = studentName;
  let tdShowSurname = document.createElement('td');
  tdShowSurname.innerText = studentSurname;
  let tdShowPoints = document.createElement('td');
  tdShowPoints.innerText = studentPoints;
  let tdShowDidPass = document.createElement('td');
  tdShowDidPass.innerText = PassNot;

  tr.appendChild(tdShowID);
  tr.appendChild(tdShowName);
  tr.appendChild(tdShowSurname);
  tr.appendChild(tdShowPoints);
  tr.appendChild(tdShowDidPass);
  tr.appendChild(btnDelete);
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);

}

// Logic
function checkIfStudentExists(studentId) {
  return students.some(student => student.id === studentId);
}

// Create Student
let btnSubmit = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
btnSubmit.onclick = function() {
  createStudent();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href='./style/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <title>Student App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="formField" class='flx'>
      <label for='studentID'>Student ID</label>
      <input id='studentID' name='studentID' placeholder='student ID' required>
      <label for='studentName'>Student Name</label>
      <input id='studentName' name='studentName' placeholder='student name' required>
      <label for='studentSurname'>Student Surname</label>
      <input id='studentSurname' name='studentSurname' placeholder='student surname' required>
      <label for='studentPoints'>Student Points</label>
      <input id='studentPoints' name='studentPoints' placeholder='student points' required>
      <button id='btnSubmit'>Submit</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="results">
      <table id='table'>
        <th>
          <td>Student ID</td>
          <td>Student Name</td>
          <td>Student Surname</td>
          <td>Student Points</td>
          <td>Student Grade</td>
          <td>Delete Record</td>
        </th>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='./js/app.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. Creating tables in javascript confuses me a little bit.